# sparse bundle adjustment implementation c/c++

Tags: c++, debugging, camera, computer-vision

Can someone explain to me, what parameters the following function awaits and what they are used for?
I have problems to understand the given description. I think I pass the wrong arguments which leads to memory exceptions. Sadly the exceptions cannot be debugged because it is external code from a library.

This function is used to compute the 3D positions of vertices given only the projection of these points at various images that show the 3D scene from different views.

Here the function header:

`int sba_motstr_levmar_x(`

```
const int n,   /* number of points */
const int ncon,/* number of points (starting from the 1st) whose parameters should not be modified.
               * All B_ij (see below) with i<ncon are assumed to be zero
               */
const int m,   /* number of images */
const int mcon,/* number of images (starting from the 1st) whose parameters should not be modified.
                          * All A_ij (see below) with j<mcon are assumed to be zero
                          */


char *vmask,  /* visibility mask: vmask[i, j]=1 if point i visible in image j, 0 otherwise. nxm */
double *p,    /* initial parameter vector p0: (a1, ..., am, b1, ..., bn).
               * aj are the image j parameters, bi are the i-th point parameters,
               * size m*cnp + n*pnp
               */
const int cnp,/* number of parameters for ONE camera; e.g. 6 for Euclidean cameras */
const int pnp,/* number of parameters for ONE point; e.g. 3 for Euclidean points */
double *x,    /* measurements vector: (x_11^T, .. x_1m^T, ..., x_n1^T, .. x_nm^T)^T where
               * x_ij is the projection of the i-th point on the j-th image.
               * NOTE: some of the x_ij might be missing, if point i is not visible in image j;
               * see vmask[i, j], max. size n*m*mnp
               */
double *covx, /* measurements covariance matrices: (Sigma_x_11, .. Sigma_x_1m, ..., Sigma_x_n1, .. Sigma_x_nm),
               * where Sigma_x_ij is the mnp x mnp covariance of x_ij stored row-by-row. Set to NULL if no
               * covariance estimates are available (identity matrices are implicitly used in this case).
               * NOTE: a certain Sigma_x_ij is missing if the corresponding x_ij is also missing;
               * see vmask[i, j], max. size n*m*mnp*mnp
               */
const int mnp,/* number of parameters for EACH measurement; usually 2 */
void (*func)(double *p, struct sba_crsm *idxij, int *rcidxs, int *rcsubs, double *hx, void *adata),
                                          /* functional relation describing measurements. Given a parameter vector p,
                                           * computes a prediction of the measurements \hat{x}. p is (m*cnp + n*pnp)x1,
                                           * \hat{x} is (n*m*mnp)x1, maximum
                                           * rcidxs, rcsubs are max(m, n) x 1, allocated by the caller and can be used
                                           * as working memory
                                           */
void (*fjac)(double *p, struct sba_crsm *idxij, int *rcidxs, int *rcsubs, double *jac, void *adata),
                                          /* function to evaluate the sparse Jacobian dX/dp.
                                           * The Jacobian is returned in jac as
                                           * (dx_11/da_1, ..., dx_1m/da_m, ..., dx_n1/da_1, ..., dx_nm/da_m,
                                           *  dx_11/db_1, ..., dx_1m/db_1, ..., dx_n1/db_n, ..., dx_nm/db_n), or
                                           * (using HZ's notation),
                                           * jac=(A_11, B_11, ..., A_1m, B_1m, ..., A_n1, B_n1, ..., A_nm, B_nm)
                                           * Notice that depending on idxij, some of the A_ij and B_ij might be missing.
                                           * Note also that A_ij and B_ij are mnp x cnp and mnp x pnp matrices resp. and
                                           * should be stored in jac in row-major order.
                                           * rcidxs, rcsubs are max(m, n) x 1, allocated by the caller and can be used
                                           * as working memory
                                           *
                                           * If NULL, the Jacobian is approximated by repetitive func calls and finite
                                           * differences. This is computationally inefficient and thus NOT recommended.
                                           */
void *adata,       /* pointer to possibly additional data, passed uninterpreted to func, fjac */ 

const int itmax,   /* I: maximum number of iterations. itmax==0 signals Jacobian verification followed by immediate return */
const int verbose, /* I: verbosity */
const double opts[SBA_OPTSSZ],
                   /* I: minim. options [\mu, \epsilon1, \epsilon2, \epsilon3, \epsilon4]. Respectively the scale factor for
                    * initial \mu, stopping thresholds for ||J^T e||_inf, ||dp||_2, ||e||_2 and (||e||_2-||e_new||_2)/||e||_2
                    */
double info[SBA_INFOSZ]
                   /* O: information regarding the minimization. Set to NULL if don't care
                    * info[0]=||e||_2 at initial p.
                    * info[1-4]=[ ||e||_2, ||J^T e||_inf,  ||dp||_2, mu/max[J^T J]_ii ], all computed at estimated p.
                    * info[5]= # iterations,
                    * info[6]=reason for terminating: 1 - stopped by small gradient J^T e
                    *                                 2 - stopped by small dp
                    *                                 3 - stopped by itmax
                    *                                 4 - stopped by small relative reduction in ||e||_2
                    *                                 5 - stopped by small ||e||_2
                    *                                 6 - too many attempts to increase damping. Restart with increased mu
                    *                                 7 - stopped by invalid (i.e. NaN or Inf) "func" values; a user error
                    * info[7]= # function evaluations
                    * info[8]= # Jacobian evaluations
                    * info[9]= # number of linear systems solved, i.e. number of attempts for reducing error
                    */
```

)

For better reading please visit this link and scroll to "available functions":

http://www.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/sba/#documentation

This is also the official homepage of this library.

Comment: Wow, wonder how the writer of that function managed to make it a part of the public API with a straight face.

Comment: There is *extensive* documentation available for that library, read the PDF. It is pretty much pointless trying to use it without understanding what the parameters do. It is painful, yes, but there is no way of describing here in short for what the authors supply several papers.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, bundle adjustments are iterative techniques that require a reasonable initial estimate of the external camera parameters. Do you have that? If not, the Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer can converge to a local minimum and you will end up with useless results. Other resources that might interest you can be found here. I don't think they require good initial estimates:

**Resource I:**

> http://www.maths.lth.se/vision/downloads/
>
> Two View Geometry Estimation with Outliers
>
> C++ code for finding the relative orientation of two calibrated
>   cameras in presence of outliers. The obtained solution is optimal in
>   the sense that the number of inliers is maximized.

**Resource II:**

> http://www.halcon.com/halcon/download/documentation/reference-9.0/hdevelop/toc_tools_stereo.html
>
> `vector_to_rel_pose`
>
> Compute the relative orientation between two
>   cameras given image point correspondences and known camera parameters
>   and reconstruct 3D space points.

Comment: Yes, I have estimates of the projection matrix of every image. Thank you again for your research!